# Is there a standard way in Spring Boot Actuators of checking the health of child services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Suppose I have Spring Boot service A which depends on (calls) Spring Boot service B.

```
A -> B
```

Spring Boot [Actuators](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) can tell me if A is up.

https://A/health

What I want to know is if B is up, by calling A.

https://A/integratedhealth

My question is: **Is there a standard way in Spring Boot Actuators of checking the health of child services?**
(or do I just have to build a custom actuator service?)

Comment: What's wrong with making a normal request to `B` and getting an error response back?

Comment: Because A->B is replicated in 100 scenarios, and there isn't a clear view of all those relationships. For the person responsible for keeping these up and available, we need a clear view of what downstream outage has what effect upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot provides a lot of Health Indicators out of the box. However, you can add your own custom health indicator by implementing `HealthIndicator` interface (`ReactiveHealthIndicator` for reactive apps):

```
@Component
public class ServiceBHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    
    private final String message_key = "Service B";

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        if (!isRunningServiceB()) {
            return Health.down().withDetail(message_key, "Not Available").build();
        }
        return Health.up().withDetail(message_key, "Available").build();
    }
    private Boolean isRunningServiceB() {
        Boolean isRunning = true;
        // Your logic here
        return isRunning;
    }
}
```

If you combine it with other health indicators like the one before, you can get a health endpoint response in a way like this:

```
{
   "status":"DOWN",
   "details":{
      "serviceB":{
         "status":"UP",
         "details":{
            "Service B":"Available"
         }
      },
      "serviceC":{
         "status":"DOWN",
         "details":{
            "Service C":"Not Available"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can find more information about [custom health checks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators) and [endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints) in the spring boot documentation.